# Python способен на серверно-клиентские отношения?

Tags: python, сервер

На Python-е можно создать сайт, способный как на банальный парсинг новостей и заканчивая клоном Вконтакте? Что почитать в этой области?Навыков в этой области никаких,к моему сожалению не могу осуществить даже банальное подключение к базе данных

Comment: Да, способен. Вы могли бы узнать все интересующее, просто введя в гугл "python web framework".

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть книги, курсы по этой тематике

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Более того, одним из основных назначений питона являются "серверно-клиентские отношения". Погуглите Django или Pyramid. Рекомендую все же первый ибо популярнее. Да и ORM базы данных, сведет работу с БД до уровня питоного кода без SQL запросов.

Comment: А существуют книги, курсы связанные с Django, Piramid? Или хотя бы о серверно-клиентских отношениях в целом?

Comment: Ну это уже в гугл. Джанго достаточно крупный фраемворк, по нему должны быть и курсы, и книги. Возможно, если вы в большом городе живете, то у вас есть какие нибудь курсы. Если же нет, то учитесь гуглить, ибо придется много и часто, что бы понять как то работает.